# Bash - Replacing from a pattern to another pattern and everything in between

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file like this:

> 1. directory Test/Movie1
> 2. Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
> 3. @
> 4. directory Test/Movie2
> 5. Quote2 -rw-rw-r-- 24 2 1
> 6. @
> 7. ...(file goes on)

I would like this output:

> 1. directory Test/Movie1
> 2. Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
> 3. @
> 4. 
> 5. 
> 6. 
> 7. ...

I already tried this command:

```
sed '0,/'"Test\/Quote1"'/d;/@/,$d' header.txt
```

but it doesn't give me the desired output.
Thank you for your help

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to recreate some shell command to format the file "header.txt"
If I type

```
rm Test/Movie2
```

My script being something like that:

```
while read -a line
do
 if [[ "${line[0]}" == "rm" ]]; then
  sed -i "/${line[1]}/"'s/.*//' header.txt #replacing Test/Movie2 by blank line

done
```

Now, I would like to replace by blank lines everything under "directory Test/Movie2" until the next delimiter "@"

Comment: There are many ways to produce that output from the given input, including just printing those hard-coded lines. If you'd like help, tell us what your actual transformation algorithm is. Posting a script that does not do what you want doesn't tell us what you want.

Comment: I edited my post, I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `sed` expression, I think that what you wanted to use is:

```
sed '/Test\/Movie2/,/@/d;' header.txt
```

In other words: delete from pattern `Test/Movie2` to following `@` (included). It gives the output you want.

**Edit**: Command above will completely delete the lines between patterns.

Here is another command line which will, instead, replace them with blank lines:

```
sed '/Test\/Movie2/,/@/g;' header.txt
```

(Instead of deleting pattern with `d` command and printing nothing, we load and print content of `sed` hold space, which is empty.)

Comment: Instead of deleting the lines I would like to replace them by blank lines

Comment: That is indeed much more elegant than mine. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

This will only prints blank lines after first found `@` (It gives what I show in your post, but I guess its not what you want)

```
awk 'f {$0=""} /@/ {f=1} 1' file
directory Test/Movie1
Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
@



.
```

`.` is just to make this page show the blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

IN_FILE="test.txt"

remove(){
    [[ $1 ]] || error
    awk -v dir="$1" 'BEGIN{np=0; w=0}
    ($2 == dir){np=1; w=0}
    (np == 1 && $0 == "@"){np=0; w=1}
    {if(np == 0 && w == 0){print $0} else {print ""; w=0}}' "$IN_FILE"
}

bye(){
    echo "Bye..."
    exit 0
}

error(){
    echo "Invalid command" >&2
}

while true; do
    read -rp "> " command
    set -- "$command"
    case "$1" in
        rm) remove "$2" ;;
        exit) bye ;;
        *) error ;;
    esac
done
```

Demonstration :

```
$ cat test.txt
directory Test/Movie1
Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
@
directory Test/Movie2
Quote2 -rw-rw-r-- 24 2 1
@
$ ./test.sh
> rm something
directory Test/Movie1
Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
@
directory Test/Movie2
Quote2 -rw-rw-r-- 24 2 1
@
> rm Test/Movie1



directory Test/Movie2
Quote2 -rw-rw-r-- 24 2 1
@
> rm Test/Movie2
directory Test/Movie1
Quote1 -rw-rw-r-- 63 1 1
@



> exit
Bye...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each set of lines beginning with "directory" and ending with "@" represents a record, and you want to be able to remove a record (set of lines) from the file by specifying what comes after "directory" on that line.

If the environment variable named "movie" contains what you want to remove, this will output the same list absent the movie record you specified:

```
movie="Test/Movie2"
sed -r ":a;N;\$!ba;s~(\n?)directory ${movie}\n[^@]*@\n?~\1~" < header.txt
```

If instead you want to modify the file in place, you can use "-i":

```
movie="Test/Movie2"
sed -r -i ":a;N;\$!ba;s~(\n?)directory ${movie}[^@]*@\n?~\1~" header.txt
```

I used a tilde (~) rather than the the usual forward slash (/) to separate the subtitution components, to prevent any slashes in the movie record (e.g. "Test/Movie2") from confusing sed. Also, the stuff before "s~" makes sed consider the whole file as a single line, to permit finding and replacing across newlines.

Note this will only work with GNU sed, as is commonly found in Linux. If you are on OS X or BSD, sed is more limited, so you can either install GNU sed, or use this:

```
movie="Test/Movie2"
tr "\n" "\177" < header.txt \
| sed -E "s~("$'\x7F'"?)directory ${movie}"$'\x7F'"[^@]*@"$'\x7F'"?~\1~" \
| tr "\177" "\n"
```

Comment: Yes, that's nearly what I want to do. In fact I want to replace those lines by blank lines instead of deleting them.

Comment: Is there always going to be three lines per record, as in your example, or is it a variable number of lines per record?

Comment: It is a variable number of lines. The constant here is that there always be an "@" as a delimiter